# How to install jupyterlab extension behind corporate proxy?

Tags: python, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I am trying to install jupyterlab extension behind a corporate proxy.
I have manged to configure the `npm` config using following commands:

```
npm config set proxy http://username:password@host:port
npm config set https-proxy http://username:password@host:port
```

And it seems package has been downloaded however I am still getting following error:

`Failed to fetch package metadata for 'jupyterlab-plotly': URLError(ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))`

How to solve this issue?

Comment: this may help: https://www.jayakumar.org/linux/how-to-configure-httphttps-proxy-for-ipython-notebook-server/